# windows-1251 looks like windows-1252

Tags: windows-10, encoding

I'm using Windows 10 and I have some problem with encoding. When I got a file in windows-1251 it looks like windows is trying to encode it in winsows-1252 instead. So cyrilic is unreadable for me and it's how I see that:
Ïðîñòî äîáàâü âîäû Ñåçîí

I tried to change [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage] 1252, 1253, 1254 to c_1251.nls and reboot, but it doesn't help.

Comment: What are you opening the file with?

Comment: @Jonno, Notepad for example, but it works for every program on my PC. Even filenames in Explorer are broken if they contain cyrilic.

Comment: Suspicious this is controlled by the region setting [here](http://i.imgur.com/mWKioeV.jpg) - can you confirm what region your machine is set to? (Type `Region` in the start menu, or look under the `Control Panel`)

Comment: @Jonno I'm using ru version of windows, but there was set on English from start. Then I set it on Russian and reboot, but it is still trying to use wrong encoding (windows-1252 instead of 1251).

Comment: Whacking registry values directly is generally not as good of a plan as using the UI. I suggest looking on the Administrative tab of the desktop Region control panel item.